# Discord.py: How to get the exact word of the command from user input message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When a user sends a command message in discord, we always get the content of the user without the exact name of the command that they use for doing this command.
For example:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['bonjour','hola','nihao'])
async def hello(ctx):
   # do something
```

But, because there are aliases, users can use "hello", "bonjour", "hola", or "nihao" for calling this command. **So, is there any way to get which one the user actually types for calling this command?**

What I have tried (don't work):

`ctx.command` will always give me "hello" even if I call this command with an alias.

`ctx.command.aliases` will return me a list of aliases

So, this problem bothers me a lot. Any suggestion or help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the alias used from the message content available as `ctx.message.content`.
Something like the following should give you the exact alias

```py
alias = ctx.message.content.lstrip('prefix').split()[0]
```

Note that you'll need to substitute your bot's actual prefix and that this will only work for commands that consist of a single word (though it can be adapted to work with longer commands as well)

Comment: Thank you so much! Absolutely helpful. I always like to use async def hello(ctx, *, content:str) and make user_input = content so it doesn't have the command. So, I really forget that ctx.message.content actually includes the whole input. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctx.invoked_with`

"The command name that triggered this invocation. Useful for finding out which alias called the command.

Docs: [`discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with)